# Why does my profile say "x posts edited" but my list of revisions ">2x revisions"?

Tags: support, edits, badges

Looking at my badge progressions I noticed I am running close to reaching the silver [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) badge, which requires the user to have made edits to 80 posts.

As of writing this question, I am at **71** edits. However, I am certain I have made significantly more edits.
To check my assumption, I browsed to *All Actions>Revisions* on my profile. Here, it says I have actually made **146** revisions.

What is the reason for this discrepancy?